# How to show the value of a string in edittext

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext, textview

I need to pass a value from one activity to another. I want the passed value should appear in an EditText. But when i run the following code it gives me both the EditText as empty.

**MainActivity**

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,second.class);
        i.putExtra("title", t);
        i.putExtra("descrip", s);
        startActivity(i);
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
});
```

**second activity**

```
et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fulltext);
et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
title = getIntent().getExtras().getString(title);
descp = getIntent().getExtras().getString(descp);
et2.setText(title, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
et1.setText(descp, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Suggest a fix. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot pass edit text as argument in  putExtra... instead read the string values from the edit text and pass string to the next activity..

Comment: If you are sending value through intent to another activity, in order get the values in another activity, you need retrieve values through getIntent().getExtras().getString("Key");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**STEP-1**: <***Eg:: From Activity1***>

Pass the `telefone`  into a new activity with the help of intents

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("title",telefone);
i.putExtra("descrip",telefone);
startActivity(i);
```

---

**STEP-2**: <***Eg:: From Activity2***>

Receive the string passed in another activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String title= extras.getString("title");
    String descrip= extras.getString("descrip");
}
```

---

***Hope it helps ! ..........Let me know if you need more info***

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
>    descp = getIntent().getStringExtra("descrip");